# PHP is not working while executing sh script remotely using ssh2_exec

Tags: php, shell, ssh, sh

I have a shell script `makedir.sh` as given below.

```
sudo -H sh -c '
    mkdir /usr/local/testdir;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        echo "Successfull";
    else
        echo "Unsuccessfull";
    fi
'
```

I have given privileges to a user testuser to execute shell script with sudo, but without asking password.For this I add the below line in `/etc/sudoers` file,

```
testuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And it works fine that, I could run commands with sudo, but without asking password. The above shell script also working fine without asking password, creating directory `testdir` inside `/usr/local`. My problem starts here. I want to run this shell script from a `php` file. In the current scenario the shell script is residing in a remote machine with ip address 10.3.2.0. The following is my `php` code but, while running this php code, it is not creating any directory(testdir) inside `/usr/local/` . Please advise as I am very beginner in `PHP`.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesn't exist");
if(!($con = ssh2_connect("10.3.2.0", "22")))
{
    echo "fail: unable to establish connection";
}
else
{
    if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "testuser", "abcdef"))
    {
        echo "fail: unable to authenticate ";
    }
    else
    {
        $stream = ssh2_exec($con, "./makedir.sh");
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $item = "";
        while ($input = fread($stream,4096)) {
               $item .= $input;
        }
        echo $item;
    }
}

?>
```

**SHELL SCRIPT - `makedir.sh` (residing at 10.3.2.0 - the same above shell script)**

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -H sh -c '
    mkdir /usr/local/testdir;
    if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
        echo "Successfull";
    else
        echo "Unsuccessfull";
    fi
'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know, sudo commands do not work from ssh2 module of php. you will need to connect as the user who has permissions to the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Well... Question was a year ago xD but still i may halp
to use sudo with ssh2_exec you need to a little trick. It is unsafe and not recommended but if you have no other choice use

```
ssh2_exec($connection, "echo sudopw | yourscript.sh" . PHP_EOL);
```

and your script has to call sudo with the argument -S

```
"sudo -S mkdir folder"
```

should work